# Помогите с React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, веб-программирование

начал изучать React и с толкнулся одной проблемой.

Почему когда метод `prompt` вызывается внутри кода функции Reacta, то он вызывается два раза и два раза просит ввести число, а когда вызывается во вне функции Reacta один раз как и должно быть.
Надо, чтобы `prompt` вызывался один раз как и должно быть.
Вот код:

```
// let age = prompt("Сколько Вам лет?"); // Снаружи
export default function App() {
  let isAdult = true;
  let age = prompt("Сколько Вам лет?"); // Внутри
  let text;
  if (Number(age) > 18) {
    text = <p>Вам больше 18!</p>;
  } else {
    text = <p>Вам меньше 18 :( </p>;
  }
  return text;
}
```

Comment: опросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе.**

Comment: ссылка битая. не работает

Comment: @Grundy исправил

Comment: @Kromster каким образом надо подключать код с React?

Comment: не надо удалять вопрос и задавать точно такой же. достаточно отредактировать существуюший

Comment: @Grundy отредактировал, только воспроизвести нельзя :(

Comment: не нужно торопиться. [Как в "Фрагмент кода (Stack Snippet)" писать React код с поддержкой JSX?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12004/186999)

Comment: Закрыл как дубликат, проблема в `StrictMode`.